# Geospatial query in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to know if there is any pre built feature for geospatial query in AWS DynamoDB(similar to MongoDB). I have a Nodejs (AWS Lambda) based application which needs geo spatial queries. Can you guide me how i can enable geo spatial query in dynamo db and is there any sdk available for the same.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like you'd be interested in [AWS's "Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB"](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo), and you can read [Jeff Barr's post about it, here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb/).  The official SDK is in Java, but there's [an unofficial node port available on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo).

Depending on how complicated your queries might get, you might also want to take a look at the recent [AWS Database Blog post on "Z-Order Indexing for Multifaceted Queries in Amazon DynamoDB"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-1/).